# Add a Contextual Menu to WebView

Tags: cocoa, webview, nsmenu

An easy one, I think:

I want to add a contextual menu to a WebView.

In IB, I added a NSMenu to the NIB, connected it to the WebView's menu outlet, launched and expected to be able to control-click in the WebView and see the pop-up menu.  The only item I saw on the contextual menu is "reload".  I can do the same steps but connect the Menu to some other view and it works as expected.

Why doesn't the menu work the same when connect to the webview's menu outlet?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`WebView` calls the following method of its [`WebViewUIDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cat/WebUIDelegate):

```
webView:contextMenuItemsForElement:defaultMenuItems:
```

Use [`setUIDelegate:`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebView/setUIDelegate:) to set a custom UI delegate.

Comment: Note fur future readers: delegate setter is "setUIDelegate:" - no "custom" in the name.